# How do I get a logo to move to the leftt side of the page when switching from mobile to tablet and computer screen?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using repl.it for reference, https://repl.it/@hungrygoat/flexbox-mobile-first-starter-1

How do I make it so that everytime I switch from mobile to tablet and larger screens, the top logo moves to the left side of the screen?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: here you can find more details on css media query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can try css media query

```
<style>
    .logo{
    float:left;
    }
    /* On screens that are 500px wide or less */
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .logo {
        float: none;
      }
    }

      </style>
```